# Binary Search Recursion Algorithm Issue In C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

Ok, so I'm given the function

```
int bin(int value, int size, int array[])
```

I am supposed to find "value" within "array[]", but the issue at hand here is that in most cases, we have something along the lines of

```
int bin(int value, int max, int min, int array[])
```

The recursion, logically, is a lot easier on this part due to the fact I can still pass the number I am at, as well as remember the size of the array.

```
int bin(int array[], int value, int min, int max)
{
    if(max < min)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int mid = min + (max - min)/2;

        if(array[mid] > value)
            return bin(array, value, min, mid-1);
        else if(array[mid] < value)
            return bin(array, value, mid+1, max);
        else
            return mid;
    }
```

But since I can only pass 1 integer, how exactly would I adjust this algorithm for it? 
In essence, I would only be able to do something like this, but I KNOW it will not logically work. Is there a way, though, that I can see the size of the array? I tried it, but the numbers weren't crunching right.

```
   int bin(int array[], int value, int size)
    {
            int mid = size/2;

            if(array[mid] > value)
                return bin(array, value, size-(size/2));
            else if(array[mid] < value)
                return bin(array, value, size+(size/2));
            else
                return mid;
    }
```

Comment: please adjust your tags for 'homework' etc; your constraints sure sound like that. A hint: in C arrays are in fact pointers to the underlying datatype. So you can pass a calculated parameter 'array' to the function.

Comment: @Adriaan: Arrays aren't pointers. Arrays are arrays. However, you cannot pass arrays as function arguments, and in that context, arrays decay to pointers to the first element. That doesn't change the nature of arrays, though.

Answer (score 13):

You need to explicitly pass the base as well:

```
int
bin(int array[], int value, int size)
{
        int mid = size/2;

        if(array[mid] > value)
            return bin(array, value, size/2);
        else if(array[mid] < value)
            return bin(&array[mid], value, size/2);
        else
            return mid;
}
```

note the "&array[mid] in the "if(array[mid] < value)" case

each time, you have the correct half of the array to search, using base + offset vice min/max indices

Comment: Shouldn't size be decreasing in any call to bin()?

Comment: @erturne good catch; my code still doesn't fix all of the issues(odd/even number of elements in the array, for example), but the basic idea is there

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Thanks! Yeah, sometimes there are these oddball constraints in some of my Professor's programs.

Comment: @Ezrb3zr This requirement for a method with a different signature is very common in recursion. There is usually a public method, and then a private helper method. I have more information about it in my answer.

Comment: @Ezrb3zr hey, can you accept/upvote? It's a bit rude to say that I solved your problem, but to then just leave it at that.

Comment: Sorry dude. I rarely hop on here. There.

Comment: @Ezrb3zr except you apparently did neither

Comment: Bad buggy answer should not be accepted. new size should be mid in the first case and size - mid in the second.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of having a method with a different argument set is to make the method easy to call for the user.  This is very common in recursion.

There is the public method that is available to the user that has the
`int bin(int value, int size, int array[])` signature.

There should then be the private, internal helper method with the
`int bin(int value, int max, int min, int array[])` signature.

The point is, someone calling this method will want to pass in the size of the array, and not the start and end index (because to them, the start index should always be 0, end should always be size-1) and it is bad practice to have a method with arguments that are preset like that.

The helper method with the start and end values (min and max) is used in the recursive calls for more efficient computations, and it hides the unnecessary arguments from the user.

Your method should then look something like this:

```
int bin(int value, int size, int array[]) {
    return bin(value, size - 1, 0, array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int * binSearch (int *arr,int size, int num2Search)

{

    if(size==1)

        return ((*arr==num2Search)?(arr):(NULL));

    if(*(arr+(size/2))<num2Search)

        return binSearch(arr+(size/2)+1,(size/2),num2Search);

    if(*(arr+(size/2))==num2Search)

        return (arr+(size/2));

    return binSearch(arr,(size/2),num2Search);

}
```

in my function, you get the same parameters and return the adress of the value.